# how to ensure backward-compatibilty in a xamarin forms application?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

How do i make sure my app can run on android devices below Lollipop( version 4.03 to  4.42). I watched a xamarin university video that says xamarin forms supports android  version 4.03(ice-cream sandwich) and upwards. I also read about runtime checks and feel like this might be the answer to my problem, but how can i write runtime checks for android  when basically all my ui and logic is contained in the PCL project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to do is ensure you are using the Android AppCompat library. I think new projects use this by default now. If you have an older project that doesn't follow [these instructions](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/platform-features/android/appcompat/) to update. This will allow your app including any Material Design look and feel to run on older versions of Android.

If you do things differently based on Android version, put the code for this in the Android project and [use dependency service](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction/) to call it.

Like this:

```
    if (Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.Lollipop)
    {
        // level specific code here
    }
```

Comment: But how do i know what apis  to place within the runtime checks?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by this. You don't need to check any apis for Xamarin Forms to work on older versions of Android.

Comment: If you want to check if you are running on a particular version of Android you can do this in the Android project if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {

}

Comment: so the runtime checks should be empty? I thought you make calls to apis that are specific to an api level within the check. Like this:

Comment: if (Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.Lollipop) 
{
    builder.SetCategory(Notification.CategoryEmail);
}

Comment: No, not empty. If you need to do something based on an api level then how you just did it is correct. There are just not many instances where you would need to do it if you are using the App Compat library

Comment: Can this be affected by the runtime? I know android uses the dalvik runtime on version 4.4.2 and lower but uses the android runtime on version 5 and upwards.

Comment: U said new projects use this by default but my app is using Android.App in stead of using the Android.Support.V4. App. Doesn't that mean my app isn't using the support library?

Comment: My new Xamarin Android applications created by the Xamarin Forms template have MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity - this provides backwards compatability